# Declaring 2D char array in a class with other integer member variables as size in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, char

The class that I am using is shown below. I am parsing in data from a txt file and saving it numRows and numCols, and I want the 2D char array maze to be of the size of those dimensions that I just parsed. How can I do this? I am in college and the program assignment requires that numRows, numCols and the 2D char array be a private member of the Board class.

```
class Board
{
public:
    Board()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
            {
                maze[i][j] = emptyPos;
            }
        }
    }
    Player getPlayer() { return User; }
    void parseMazeData(int &rowStartPos, int &colStartPos);
private:
    int numRows;
    int numCols;
    char maze[numRows][numCols];
    Player User;
};
```

Comment: Ate you allowed to use C++ elements like std::vector and so on, or, is it a must to continue with C-style and use arrays?

Comment: Your approach is invalid in C++ since VLAs (variable-sized array - declared with a size that is a variable) is not valid in C++ - the array dimensions need to be fixed at compile time, not based on variables read in at run time. Try using `std::vector` - which represents a dynamically allocated array.  You can represent a resizeable two-dimensional array using either a `std::vector<char>` (with size `numRows*numCols` and then you take care of mapping two indices to a single dimension) or use a `std::vector<std::vector<char> >` (and then ensure all `std::vector<char>` have the same dimension).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't know upfront the number of rows and columns, so you need to perform a dynamic allocation.
If my assumption is right you need to have already parsed the maze data before doing anything with the array.

So, once you parse those dimensions you can do:

```cpp
Board() {
//Parse maze data somehow before and then:
 maze = new char[nrows*ncols]
 for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) { 
   for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) { 
     maze[i][j] = emptyPos;
  }
 } 
}
```

This of course will require you to clean up this maze array in the destructor of this Board class.

A much nicer solution would be using std::vector, since it provides the cleanup for you. Think of it as a high level array with extra functionalities and safer API. This way, maze would be declared as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> maze.
```

With that you would not need to write a destructor yourself and your constructor would be like:

```
Board() {
//Parse maze data somehow before and then:
 maze.size(numRows);
 for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) { 
    maze.at(i).size(numCols);
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) { 
       maze[i][j] = emptyPos;
    }
  } 
}
```